# nginx with radius authentication and ldap group authorization

Tags: python, nginx, ldap, radius

I am trying to move nginx auth from ldap to radius authentication which is working fine using https://github.com/qudreams/nginx-http-radius-module.

```
location / {
    auth_radius_server "radius_server1" "PAP";
    auth_radius "Restricted";
    # Static content no auth
    location ~ ^/(css|app|img|vendor|font|config.js|favicon.ico) {
              allow all;
    }
}
```

But I want to a way to also check the remote users ldap group and allow or deny him/her access. Tried to use http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html as a proxy and send the request to a uwsgi python server with proxy_pass it never get the request and with uwsgi_pass get an error

> "upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header
>   from upstream, client"

Any other way of going about this ?

```
location / {
    auth_radius_server "radius_server1" "PAP";
    auth_radius "Restricted";
    # Static content no auth
    location ~ ^/(css|app|img|vendor|font|config.js|favicon.ico) {
              allow all;
    }
    auth_request /hello;
}
location /hello {
    include uwsgi_params;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_no_cache $cookie_nocache  $arg_nocache$arg_comment;
    proxy_no_cache $http_pragma     $http_authorization;
    proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_nocache $arg_nocache $arg_comment;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_pragma $http_authorization;
    #uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```